# Are case types case sensitive in CommCare?

Tags: commcare

If one of my case types is named `case` and one of my case types is named `Case` will they be treated as different case types in CommCare?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CommCare doesn't provide any specification about case-specificity in its underlying technical format, so the safest guaranteed behavior is to make is that the case types **need** to match, but to not make any assumptions that two cases with mixed cases **won't** match.